# Why is target.write ignoring my %r formatting?

Tags: python, format, operator-keyword, python-2.6

I'm trying to write a program similar to this guy's *Learn Python the Hard Way* program, near the top of the page.

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html

This is my version below. But it tells me off for using `"%r"` at the end, why does it do that? I thought that's what you're meant to do in parenthesis.

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --

from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "Would you like file %r to be overwritten?" % filename
print "Press RETURN if you do, and CTRL-C otherwise."

raw_input('> ')

print "Opening the file ..."
target = open(filename, 'w')
target.truncate()

print "Now type three lines to replace the contents of %r" % filename

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "The lines below have now overwritten the previous contests."

target.write("%r\n%r\n%r") % (line1, line2, line3)
target.close()
```

Comment: The code you have now is trying to pass the format string to the `write()` call, and then use the value returned from `write()` as a format string. Write doesn't return anything, so it shouldn't be a surprise that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place the `%` operator directly after the format string.  Take the parenthesis here:

```
target.write("%r\n%r\n%r") % (line1, line2, line3)
#                      --^
```

And move it to the end of the line:

```
target.write("%r\n%r\n%r" % (line1, line2, line3))
#                                              --^
```

---

Also, I would like to mention that performing string formatting operations with `%` is frowned upon these days.  The modern approach is to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
target.write("{0!r}\n{1!r}\n{2!r}".format(line1, line2, line3))
```

Comment: Lol that second answer has confused the pants off me. I see pointy brackets embedded and different numbers in them and ! marks. o.o

Comment: Well, I was just mentioning it because `%` formatting is slowly becoming deprecated. All of the syntax I used is explained in the link I gave. Basically, all format fields are numbered (starting from zero) and enclosed by curly braces `{...}`. The `!r` tells Python to call [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) on the arguments given. It is the same as the `r` in `%r`. Also, numbering the format fields is only necessary in Python 2.6. All newer versions of Python permit implicit numbering.

Comment: Okay cool, I'm with ya, I'll take a look at the link, and thanks!